# Notification access screen keeps popping up even after granting the permission in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I use `flutter_local_notifications` plugin and `Firebase Messaging` library in Flutter on Android 10 and I am only reacting to notifications in the `initState` method. I get the data from notification and show the appropriate screen. This works.

The problem is that the Notification access screen (screenshot) keeps popping up each time I restart the app, even though I granted all Notification access permissions.
Does anyone know how to let this screen show just once?

```dart
final m = FirebaseMessaging();
```

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   
 m.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> m) async {
       // method call is here and works
       return;
    },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> m) {
       // method call is here and works
       return;
     } ....
```

[image: notification-access-screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing `notifications: ^0.0.3` from `pubspec.yaml`.
I did not use this dependency anyway.